# Where do puppet logs go?

Tags: puppet

I ran `puppet apply` and got an error. Is there any way that I can get more details on this error?

> err: /Stage[main]/XX/Service[xx]: Failed to call refresh: Could not restart Service[xx]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/xx restart' returned 1:  at /etc/puppet/manifests/xx/xx.pp:20

Comment: Does the init script return an exit code of 0 when you manually run the `/etc/init.d/xx restart` that Puppet is attempting?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error at the moment. Are there no logs and the solution is to just try it manually and see what the error is?

Comment: What you've got pretty much is the log - the fact that it got a non-zero status code is about all the info that Puppet has.  Are you sure it's getting a good response code?  Run `/etc/init.d/xx restart; echo $?` and see what the output looks like.

Comment: Well presumably /etc/init.d/xx restart produced some error which puppet swallowed. That restart call is working fine for me now, but it's still good to know if I run into a service failing to start in the future that I need to try it manually to see what the error is. I'd accept your answer as an answer except it's a comment, so I can't :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `puppet apply --debug` to get more output. 
With puppet apply there is no logfile at all but you can redirect the output with `--logdest` to a file